# Bitlocker. Можно ли узнать пароль уже расшифрованного, разблокированного диска?

Tags: windows, шифрование

Купил ноутбук, но в нигде не могу найти ключ от диска. Некоторые время пользовался и тут возникла необходимости узнать этот ключ. Есть ли способ, если система с диском уже расшифрованная? По идее, в этом случае ключ уже должен где-то хранится. Делать вайп диска можно, но не очень хочется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю ничего о Bitlocker-е, но знаю что-то о шифровании. Потому вас могу заверить, что вы оригинальный пароль *только на базе того, что диск уже в состоянии расшифрования*, **узнать не можете** — иначе это бы была *грубая ошибка самого Bitlocker-а!*

> По идее, в этом случае ключ уже должен где-то хранится.

*Ключ* не то же самое, что *пароль.* Ключ генерируется из пароля, но таким образом, чтобы из ключа не было возможно обратно узнать пароль.

- Пароль ⇾ **ключ** ⇾ шифрование / дешифрование с помощью **ключа**

После генерирования ключа *пароль уже не нужен,* и потому нет смысла его где-то сохранять.

---

*Примечание:*

Почему **сначала пароль**, и только **на базе него ключ**? Не было бы возможно просто сразу задать ключ?

Было, но мы, люди, *имеем трудности с запоминанием долгих последовательностей из нулей и единиц.* Например, типичный 256-битовый ключ может выглядеть так:

1011101111010101001101011110110001100100100100110001110010011101011111100110111000101100111100011111000000010110000010111101100011001111010100111000011101010011111111010001110001101000001100111110100111100111101100010111011110010011100000100000101000100000

и пароль, на базе которого он сгенерировался, так: **GoodOrPoorPassword**.